# Web Forms and Core Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Web Forms website running in IIS (using forms authentication).

I've added a .NET Core 2.2 website as a sub application of the Web Forms site.

Is it possible to share authentication from the Web Forms site to the Core site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this: https://github.com/dazinator/AspNetCore.LegacyAuthCookieCompat
and was able to check for the forms auth cookie from the parent site when a requests hits the core sub application.

Then I could decrypt the forms auth cookie, to get the user info, and authenticate the user on the core site.

Not sure if this is ideal, because you know have to manage 2 cookies, but it seems to work.